# I got [TypeError: handleOutsideActionListeners is not a function] error when I write unit test code by testing-library

Tags: next.js

I am coding on a page.
the page uses `react-date-picker`

I can not get unit test code passed since I got
`TypeError: handleOutsideActionListeners is not a function` error.

does someone have any idea as a workaround?

thank you very much

Comment: Is that pointing to the source code of date picker ?